# How to add an ASCII value of a byte to an integer in golang?

Tags: go, byte, ascii, string-conversion

I'd like to get a byte[] variables' asic value added to an integer. For example, I fisrt read all input in a byte[] buffer. And then I get out a number string "123" in it. And then I can assign it to an integer by ('1' - '0')*100 + ('2' - '0')*10 + '3' - '0'. But I can not assign integers with byte variables. How can I do that with any means? Thank you very much :)

Comment: ASIC?: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application-specific_integrated_circuit

Comment: Are you just looking for [`strconv.Atoi`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Atoi)?

Comment: Yes, that can solve my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In go, you can convert byte array to string with the string() coercion and then use strconv.Atoi on it.  Presumably, you also want to use slice operations to isolate just the part of the input you want to convert.

```
package main

import (
    "strconv"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    data := []byte { 0x20, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x20 } // Embedded number
    // string(...) coercion yields a string from a byte buffer
    // Number starts at char 1, ends before char 4
    str := string(data[1:4])
    i, err := strconv.Atoi(str)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error %v\n", err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Printf("value %v\n", i)
}
```

Prints

```
value 123
```

And since go has nicely hygenic practicies, errors will be handled too.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's a little pity I can  not add the asic value of character to an integer like I do in c++ language.

Comment: You can coerce a byte value to int to parse an integral value, but it's better to use a library function that traps errors.  Also just realized that you meant ASCII rather than ASIC.

Comment: @younis: you can convert any numeric types with the rules laid out in the spec: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions (specifically under "Conversions between numeric types")

Answer (score 0):

If you need to read an integer from a stream of bytes, the fastest way would be just to [scan](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#hdr-Scanning) it with `fmt`. Example:

```
n := 0
_, err := fmt.Scanf("%d", &n)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Printf("you entered %d\n", n)
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. But I've encountered a problem when I practiced a algorithm problem. The scanf somehow took blank lines into account and it didn't get the whole data and got zeros at blank lines. It's a little awkward......[link](http://codeforces.com/contest/575/submission/20550909)

Comment: I don't get what you're saying. I run your program on my machine and it gives 8.